# Modify pandas dataframe at row i depending on values at i-1

Tags: python, pandas

I work with a pandas dataframe time series of stock price. From the stock price and a given condition I created a new column called "open long system 1 signal" ('OL_Sys1_Signal'), with a value of 1 if the condition is met, 0 if not. I have another column with "close long system 1 signal" ('CL_Sys1_Signal') to tell me when to close the position.

Now I want to create another column called 'L_Sys1_Status' in which the value of the column will be 1 as long as there is no signal to close the long position.

Here is an example of what I want to get:

Index (time series), OL_Sys1_Signal, CL_Sys1_Signal, L_Sys1_Status(what I want to create)

```
00, 0, 0, 0
01, 1, 0, 1 
02, 0, 0, 1 
03, 0, 0, 1 
04, 1, 0, 1 
05, 0, 0, 1 
06, 0, 0, 1 
07, 0, 1, 0 
08, 0, 0, 0 
09, 0, 1, 0 
10, 0, 0, 0
11, 1, 0, 1
12, 1, 0, 1
13, 1, 0, 1
15, 0, 0, 1
16, 0, 0, 1
17, 0, 0, 1
18, 0, 0, 1
19, 0, 1, 0
20, 1, 0, 1
21, 0, 0, 1
```

etc.

I initially tried the following lines of code to do that:

```
dataframe['L_Sys1_Status']=dataframe['OL_Sys1_Signal'] #duplicate
for i in range(1, len(dataframe)):
  if dataframe['L_Sys1_Status'].iloc[i-1] == 1 and dataframe['CL_Sys1_Signal'].iloc[i] == 0:
    dataframe['L_Sys1_Status'].iloc[i] = dataframe['L_Sys1_Status'].iloc[i-1]
```

This unfortunately does not work and python returns:

*SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)*

I managed to do what I wanted with iloc using the column number rather than the index and that works:

```
dataframe['L_Sys1_Status']=dataframe['OL_Sys1_Signal'] #duplicate
for i in range(1, len(dataframe)):
  if dataframe.iloc[i-1,13] == 1 and dataframe.iloc[i,12] == 0:
    dataframe.iloc[i,13] = dataframe.iloc[i-1,13]
```

But you can imagine how problematic that will be if I create new columns before these (the index is going to shift), which I probably will in the future as I try new things. I will have to change the column numbers everytime.

Is there a way to make the code more robust? I was thinking I could get the column number with 'get_loc()' to do that. But perhaps my approach is not the best and someone has a better idea?

Thanks!

AG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 1 sequences starting when OL is 1 and 0 sequences starting when CL is 1.
You can set those values and ffill the column, then set to 0 the values that would still be NaN.

Assuming that the column `L_Sys1_Status` does not exist, you can do:

```
df.loc[df['OL_Sys1_Signal'] == 1, 'L_Sys1_Status'] = 1
df.loc[df['CL_Sys1_Signal'] == 1, 'L_Sys1_Status'] = 0
df['L_Sys1_Status'] = df['L_Sys1_Status'].ffill().fillna(0).astype('int64')
```

Comment: I get the idea but it doesn't work. I edited my post to add an exemple so you understand. Thanks

Comment: @ozwald: That is the reason why we ask for [mcve] with enough data to reproduce... I have changed my post.

Comment: Second line should be df.loc[df['CL_Sys1_Signal'] == 1, 'L_Sys1_Status'] = 0 but that works! You are a god Serge merci bisous